# Can I in android show only numeric keyboard?

Tags: android

Can I in android show only numeric keyboard  ? I know that is possible on iPhone but I don't know how to do this on Android.

Comment: Please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70189238/12272687

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your xml layout for your `EditText` use :

```
    android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="phone"

in your XML