# Why is EditText repeating text when entering a not allowed char defined by "android:digits" attribute?

Tags: android, android-edittext

My `Activity` has an `EditText` as defined bellow:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="0123456789.:"
    />
```

The allowed input should be `.`, `:` and `numbers`. But if a not allowed char is typed when the `EditText` is empty the text starts to be duplicated.

For example, assuming the `EditText` is empty, type the following sequence: `abc123`.

On my device the result is `1112123`, but the expected result should be just `123`.

As this should be as simple as possible, I would not like to use an `InputFilter`.

Comment: Are you using the default keyboard? InputFilter could solve your problem quite easily in fact...

Comment: @SimonMarquis Yes, I'm.

Comment: I meant the Google keyboard, not the default on your device

Comment: I'm using the default that comes with AOSP.

Comment: Does the logcat say something?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I wish it had any clue.

Comment: I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact this has something to do with the default `InputFilter` for `android:digits` ([DigitsKeyListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.java)), the `android:inputType="text"` and the current `Keyboard`.

The keyboard suggestions can be messy when using `android:digits`. As I do not need keyboard suggestions for this specific `EditText` I changed the `android:inputType` to `textNoSuggestions` and now it is working as expected.

Comment: On some Samsung devices textNoSuggestions does not work properly. In that case, you can try android:inputType="textVisiblePassword". It would not be the proper way, but it just works.

Comment: Thank you android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" works for me