# How to show "phone" type soft keyboard on android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I accidentally saw application that shows keyboard like this:

[image]

If I set EditText inputType to number or phone, I get a different keyboard(with 4 buttons more).

So, how to show such keyboard?

Comment: Probably not the real system keyboard but some custom view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the soft keyboards provided by the system your app is running on you can always create a input method yourself.

There is a nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677)

If you just want to play around have a look at: [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: Well, it looks like not a custom keyboard in my screenshot, so I want to find a way to display that keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself:

```
  android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Comment: It will probably show password bullets to hide the input.  If you don't want that, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only