# AppCompatEditText android:digits not working?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

android:digits property of AppCompatEdittext not working properly as I aspect.

My XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="12345" />
```

But when I press number 6,7,8,9,0 previous characters repeated?
I don't know what's wrong with this?

Comment: you want allow user to input just 1 to 5 right??

Comment: add `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: I want to allow just 1 to 5 and It is also possible with onTextChangeListner(...)  android make this possible in just one line so I can use this functionality

Comment: I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Answer (score 1):

Add `inputType="number"`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="12345"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```

Comment: This is not working in my case, I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Comment: Not a relevant answer. What if someone has to only allow alpha numeric character and + and - symbol?

Answer (score 1):

At first you should add `android:inputType="number"`

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:digits="12345"
android:inputType="number"/>
```

Secondly

```
 private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {

                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                     // Logic in here
                .setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("12345"));
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {

                }
        };
```