# Text Input EditText digits are Not Working ? show Only Characters like "abcxyz" and also need to avoid Number and symbols in edittext(TextInputLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
           android:id="@+id/value_text_input_edittext"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:saveEnabled="false"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black"
           android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
           android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
           android:inputType="text"
           android:textSize="14sp"
           android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
           app:colorAccent="@android:color/black"
           app:font="@font/proxima_nova_semibold" />
```

I have tried `XML` Layout and `pragmatically` but it is not working its allowing number and symbols also:

```
 valueTextInputEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
  valueTextInputEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
```

I have tried with `EditText` its working fine, but am using in my project `TextInputLayout` so i need `TextInputLayout` function so need help

Comment: try removing inputType

Comment: Are you getting any crash?

Comment: If you want input only digits you can use `android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"`

Comment: i need to show only char lik abcd

Comment: no @RajshreeTiwari

Comment: @KannaSMahesh you want only characters right, because i tried your code so i am able to type only characters not number

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari i am using TextInputLayout Editetext not normal EditText

Comment: i used the same code, did you add design support library in your gradle, show your gradle file in updated code

Comment: @YoLo tried but no luck

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle, becuase the code is correct it is working at my end.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari ya your right but its also allowing number lik 123 and symbol "@##$" i dont want number and symbol in my edittext

Comment: @KannaSMahesh don't do it programtically and update your question with build.gradle

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari 
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3' 
used thiz

Comment: @KannaSMahesh i told that update in current question or do one thing paste your file here and share the link :- https://codeshare.io/5w3q1B

Comment: @KannaSMahesh what is your compilsdkversion?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari compilsdkversion is 28

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari hi while use InputFilter  its working...thanks for ur effort

Comment: I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Answer (score 0):

You can set filter to your `TextInputEditText`. Try below code

```
 public class InputFilterCharacter implements InputFilter {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if(isCharacter(source.toString()))
        {
            return source.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isCharacter(String s) {
        return s.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*");
    }

}
```

And set your filter

```
  TextInputEditText et = findViewById(R.id.value_text_input_edittext);

  et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterCharacter()});
```