# Difference between NumberFlagDecimal and NumberFlagSigned

Tags: android, xamarin

I just want a numeric keypad in my android Xamarin application.

so which is better input type and why ?

Answer (score 2):

from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)

> public static final int TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
>
> Flag of TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: the number is decimal, allowing a decimal
>   point to provide fractional values.
>
> public static final int TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
>
> Flag of TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: the number is signed, allowing a positive
>   or negative sign at the start.

Comment: ok thnx for info, i just want number on my keyboard not any decimal option on my keyboard so which inputtype is perfect ?

Comment: Why not try them both and see which one works better for you?

Comment: I  tried both but both are having "." and "-" as into keyboard

Answer (score 2):

If you want nothing but numbers allowed to be entered in your EditText` just set the digits property:

```
<EditText
.
.
.
android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
android:digits="1234567890"
./>
```

You can also use the set the InputType as TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER

This will disable everything else but numbers good luck.

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER  have "." nad "-" in your keyboard

Comment: My friend did you Try the above method i have added the digits to remove `.` and `-`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

If you want a keyboard only with number and without any other characters, you can do following steps:

Set your `keyboard`'s `inputType`: `numberPassword`

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
         />
```

Then you will get a keyboard with only with numbers, however you will find numbers in `EditText` is **invisible** as security enter.

If you want to make the numbers `visible` in the `EditText`, you need to customize `PasswordTransformationMethod`:

```
private class NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod
    {
        public override ICharSequence GetTransformationFormatted(ICharSequence source, View view)
        {
            return source;
        }
    }
```

And finally we need implementing it to the `EditText` in order to display the characters typed.

```
 EditText myedit = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit);
 myedit.TransformationMethod = new NumericKeyBoardTransformationMethod();
```

I find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only) and I translate it into C# code. Hope it will help you.

[image: numberKeyboard]