# Numeric Soft Keyboard on Android on empty Activity

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to call a soft keyboard with numbers, but I don’t understand how to do this. I can call just a pogram keyboard, but how can I make it so that there are only numbers?

in all examples they usually use editText with inputType="number", but I have an empty activity on which I need to call the soft keyboard with numbers.

Comment: I want to add how I call the soft keyboard

 `code` imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethod.SHOW_FORCED,1); `code`

Comment: Please refer this : -  [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only) .  with `EditText` , you can use the `android:digit="0123456789"`

Comment: What do you mean you have an "empty activity"? Do you not have a layout that provides the UI of your activity? What is displaying your EditText on the screen?

Comment: So if I understand, you want to call keyboard with numbers programmaticly without EditText?

Comment: if you dont have edittext what is the purpose of keyboard? where that text suppose to be inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, you can't without setting an input type.

You can display the keyboard any time you like by calling:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

But in order to set it to set the keyboard to numeric, you need to set the input type, as shown below:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

or in `xml`

```
android:inputType = "numberPassword"
```

Comment: this is well known answer but question is, he do not have edit text.And he wants to display number keyboard on empty activity.

Comment: Yes I answered his question, if you read what I said `The simple answer is, you can't without setting an input type`. There is nothing wrong with my answer and no reason to downvote.