# how to retain consistent spacing between characters when toggling from inputType numberPassword to showing numbers

Tags: android

after setting my edittext's inputtype to numberpassword and following this fantastic post [EditText view with keyboard number only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only) , I'm finding that the bullets when in password form take up considerably less space than the numbers they transform from and to.  I was wondering how to fix this such that the bullets take up the same x-space as the numbers do.

[image]