# Display keyboard for numers when inputType set to 'text'

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I would like to display for users keybaord with numbers, dot and comma when my input place field is set to
`<item name="android:inputType">text</item>`.

I don't want set inputType for numberDecimal cause it do not accept comma. Or maybe there is other way to force user to use comma instead of dot when entering floats?

Greetings

Comment: I hope this is helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/how-do-you-set-the-edittext-keyboard-to-only-consist-of-numbers-on-android

Comment: Maybe you need to customize the soft keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-can-you-make-a-custom-keyboard-in-android

Comment: For the comma dilemma you could use 'yourEditText.toString.replace(".", ",")

Comment: Will try all the suggestions and will be back with result

Comment: None of this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this but you need to handle invalid input yourself or add `TextWatcher` to check for input while typing

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789,."
```