# How to use numbers in EditText Preference androidx?

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx, android-preferences

I need to display number keyboard in EditText Preference which is androidx.

proxy.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <EditTextPreference
        android:dialogTitle="edittext_dialogtitle_proxy_port"
        android:key="edittext_key_proxy_port"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:summary="Summary"
        android:title="Port"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    EditTextPreference mPortField;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.proxy);
        mPortField = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("edittext_key_proxy_port");
        mPortField.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {

            }
        });
 }
```

I am not getting number keypad

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466790/3161139 ?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I am not able to use EditText in AndroidX's EditTextPreference

Comment: Have you tried to use `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`?

Comment: Yes @artman I tried but still not working. Still keyboard is not displaying only numbers

Comment: Too bad. I couldn't manage to display numeric keyboard on EditTextPreference for my TV app. It's also using `androidx.preference.EditTextPreference`. So I think there will be no difference for mobile as well. Guess we will have to wait for support. In my mobile app I use regular fragment and `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` and manage saving to settings myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [this doc](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style#Type) `android:inputType` is applicable only for `EditText`, not `EditTextPreference` (which isn't [extending `EditText`, `DialogPreference` instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference)). but you already figured out how to get `EditText` hidden in `EditTextPreference`, so maybe just set digit limitation programmatically inside `onBindEditText` with below line

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

(more info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/how-do-you-set-the-edittext-keyboard-to-only-consist-of-numbers-on-android/30466790#30466790))

Comment: Sorry but getEditText() is not working in androidx EditTextPreference. getEditText() is applicable only for android.preference.EditTextPreference.  I am using androidx

Comment: Sorry, but I've never posted `getEditText()` line suggestion... I've posted `setInputType` to paste inside `onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText)`. fields `inputType` and `digits` may be removed from prefs XML, they won't work for `<EditTextPreference` tag

Comment: Wow Perfect!! :-) Thank you so much.! @snachmsm